# JSF advantage of ManagedEntity vs UnManagedEntity

Tags: jsf, entity, managed-bean

I have recently started studying JSF and have stumbled accross the following two ways to include entities into a Controller Managed bean. One by direct injection with the entity as a `ManagedBean`, the other with the entity as a non-managed bean simply as an instance variable which is initialized at `@PostConstruct`.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of one way or another? The second is usually showed as the "right way" however it seems that it's more complicated to maintain.

**Non-Managed Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Book {
 //...attributes
}

@ManagedBean
public class BookController {

   private Book book;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
     book = new Book();

   }


}
```

**Managed Entity**

```
@Entity
@ManagedBean
public class Book implements Serializable {
      //...attributes
}

@ManagedBean
public class BookController {

     @ManagedProperty(name="#{customer}")
     private Book book;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Entities got their own lifecycle and are already managed by JPA. It's not recommended (the CDI specification strongly forbids it) to declare entities as managed beans. Better keep a reference to the entity in your controller - Non-Managed Entity in your case.